# TinkerPop: Filter by Edge not connected with an Edge

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

Sample database: [TinkerPop Modern](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/images/tinkerpop-modern.png)

---

**Objective**: Find People who have not developed a Software.

ie. Vertex type "Person" that is not directly connected to Vertex type "Software"

**Person connected to Software** *[Works]*

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").as("from")
.project("title", "node")
    .by(select("from").unfold().values("name").fold())
    .by(select("from").unfold().label().fold())
```

**Find Person not connected to Software** *[Does not work]*

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").as("from")
.filter(both().not(hasLabel("Software")))
.project("title", "node")
    .by(select("from").unfold().values("name").fold())
    .by(select("from").unfold().label().fold())
```

I believe its ignoring an edge that does not satisfy the condition, but does not skip the Vertex.

Tried to do a loop but did not find an example for it.

*Cypher Query equivalent (for reference only): MATCH (n:People) WHERE NOT (n)--(:Software) RETURN n*

---

Sample database:

[image]

Comment: gremlin user group post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/1JtPV4mI8PA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you just need to change your filter criteria:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').
......1>   filter(__.not(outE('created'))).
......2>   project("title", "node").
......3>     by('name').
......4>     by(label)
==>[title:vadas,node:person]
```

As you can see, you also don't need to select back to that `as()` step for any reason - you already have that vertex as the current traverser in `project()`.

Comment: it works :D thanks... now just I am trying to figure out why my syntax failed